# Trying compiling in minix3

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, system-calls, minix

I'm using minix3 on VMware Player and i'm having trouble compiling a system call.
I actually tried to see if i can add a simple command in a system call just to see that working and i put a simple `printf("my message");` in `protect.c` file which it is on `usr/src/servers/vfs`.

I saved it, and tried to compile it with `make` command while i am on vfs directory.
It says that `protect.c` is up to date.

I try change a file's owner (`protect.c` has the chown mode code in it) and i'm waiting as a result my message. Instead it's just run the command correctly without printing my message.

I assume that i did something wrong with compiling and i'm searching for hours over the internet trying to fix it. But the only command that cames repeatedly is `make hdboot`. I know that this command it's not gonna work because i'm using minix3 as a virtual OS, but i tried it just to confirmed it and as i said didn't work.

Is anyone know anything about compiling in minix3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your problem is indeed with compilation and you've implemented your system call correctly then after making any edits in /usr/src you should call "make install" from /usr/src/releasetools and then call "reboot" to restart minix